# Lazy Load Exception in a foreach loop with try/catch inside

Tags: hibernate, groovy, foreach, lazy-loading

I have the following code:
The `User` is a Hibernate domain.

```
for(User user : users) {
            try {
                function()
                //log the user content 
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                log.warn("Exception " + ex.toString() + ". Continue...")
            }
}
```

Some fields of `User` are beeing lazy loaded. And in a cases when `function()` throws exception the lazy loading is throwing `no Session` exception and accordingly the user content logging is broken.
While

```
for(int i=0; i<users.size();++i) {
            var user = users.get(i)
            try {
                function()
                //log the user content 
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                log.warn("Exception " + ex.toString() + ". Continue...")
            }
}
```

works fine.
I really need to understand the root cause of this so any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Is `users` an instance of some class that implements `java.util.List`?

Comment: yes it is list.

Comment: I have attempted to recreate that. behavior and I cannot.  Can you link to a sample project which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: it seems the problem must be related to the iterator but I am not sure what combination of factors causes the problem to manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what is going on, but probably at some point an exception is being thrown, which clears the Hibernate session, and the next time a proxy is accessed it throws the `LazyInitializationException`.

see e.g. https://docs.grails.org/5.1.7/guide/single.html#declarativeTransactions

> [Transactional] methods are wrapped in a transaction and automatic rollback occurs if a method throws an exception (both Checked or Runtime exceptions)

https://docs.grails.org/5.1.7/guide/single.html#transactionsRollbackAndTheSession mentions that

> When a transaction is rolled back the Hibernate session used by GORM is cleared. This means any objects within the session become detached and accessing uninitialized lazy-loaded collections will lead to a LazyInitializationException.

I assume this is what happens in your case as well. I'm not sure why it does not occur in the second code snipped you posted, maybe the `users.get(i)` code actually fetches the object again from your db.

Other Workarounds include:

- rework your code so no exception is thrown and the session is preserved
- use a separate session for each object (`User.withNewSession { ... }`) -> bad for performance
- re-fetch objects after an exception occurs (also not optimal if you have to do it too often)